# jQuery: slideDown does jump

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown, slideup

i have the following function.

```
function notificationBoxOutput(type, message) {
    if (type == "success") { $('.notificationBox').removeClass('warning').addClass('success'); }
    if (type == "warning") { $('.notificationBox').removeClass('success').addClass('warning'); }
    $('.notificationBox').html('<b>' + type + ':</b>&nbsp;' + message);
    $('.notificationBox').slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
}
```

and the following css

```
div.notificationBox
{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    background: #333333;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    opacity:0.85;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    display: none;
}

div.warning { background-color: #990000; display: block; }
div.success { background: #009900; display: block; }
```

So when the function is fired the notificationBox should slideDown from top, show its message and after 3secs slideUp again.

Any idea why only slideUp works fine as animation but slideDown does jump to without animation?

Comment: This is off-topic but: ***Every time*** you do `$('.notificationBox')`, jQuery has to go off and search the DOM from top to bottom. Rather than repeatedly calling the function, *call it once*, store the result in a variable, and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS. Remove `display:block` declaration in your `success` and `warning` classes and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the last line of your jquery with this...

```
$('.notificationBox').slideDown( function() {
    $('.notificationBox').delay(3000).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: in this case it still jumps but doesn't slide back up at all.

Comment: shouldn't be a problem with it. Check out this link to see it working... http://jsfiddle.net/NnY35/ (edit: just saw the accepted answer... that would be why this works!)

Answer (score 0):

It should work as-is once you remove the `display:block` from the `.success` and `.warning` classes, and let jquery handle that..

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Qznrk/3/
(*changed code to store a reference to the notification and use that, and chained some methods together as well..*)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried you code. I have added two buttons to call the function notificationBoxOutput.

```
<html><head>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function notificationBoxOutput(type, message) {
    if (type == "success") {
       $('.notificationBox').removeClass('warning').addClass('success'); }
    if (type == "warning") { 
        $('.notificationBox').removeClass('success').addClass('warning'); }
    $('.notificationBox').html('<b>' + type + ':</b>&nbsp;' + message);
    $('.notificationBox').slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
}
</script>
<style>
div.notificationBox
{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    background: #333333;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    opacity:0.85;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    display: none;
}

div.warning { background-color: #990000; display: block; }
div.success { background: #009900; display: block; }
</style>
</head><body>
    <div class="notificationBox">Hi</div>
    <button onclick='notificationBoxOutput("success","success")' >success</button>
    <button onclick='notificationBoxOutput("warning","warning")' >warning</button>
</body></html>
```

I found that the jumpping issue is happening only when I click on success button first and then warning button before 3000 ms. This is also happening when we click warning button first and then success button within 3 sec.

To solve this problem add this code before checking *type* in *notificationBoxOutput()*

```
$('.notificationBox').hide();
```

Also visit http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slidedown-animation-jump-revisited/. JQuery has a bug. This link may help you.